# What happens to enumerators if the original collection modified .NET

Tags: .net, generics, collections

I have a generic Tree class which will implement ICollection< T > (and hence IEnumerable< T > and IEnumerable).

For this I have to implement a TreeEnumerator class.

Every call to Tree.GetEnumerator() will return a new instance of TreeEnumerator.

I have 2 questions:

1. If there are many TreeEnumerator objects floating around and the underlying Tree changes then what happens ? how to handle that ?
2. Is it better to do a CopyToArray all the tree elements (inside TreeEnumerator for easy array traversal) when TreeEnumerator is created or do the traversal one step at time with each MoveNext ?

I know CopyToArray is easy one time traversal but costs on space.

**EDIT** :

After getting to know of version mechanism:

Can you point to an example code of this versioning mechanism ? There must be standard naming and way to access , because foreach loop will need this check with each MoveNext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, structural changes to the underlying collection invalidate any existing iterators. This can be implemented using a "version number" in the collection, which can be checked on each iteration step.

For example, from the docs for [`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

(In practice, it will throw `InvalidOperationException`.)

Note that the concurrent collections in .NET 4 explicitly allow the collection to be changed *without* invalidating the iterator. Typically the iterator will only see the original elements, as if a snapshot has been taken when `GetEnumerator()` was called.

Comment: @Jon Does the class need to keep track of version numbers ? Basically How to support invalidation ?

Comment: @Munish: The collection has a version number which it updates, and the iterator knows the version number the collection was at when the iterator was created.

Comment: @Jon I think my question in comment was not clear. So is this version number hidden from programmer ? i mean is it automatically supported or do I need to do  something to update version while modification and make checks for version while iterating etc.

Comment: @Munish: The version number is hidden from the *user* of the class, but if you're *implementing* a collection, you need to put in that machinery yourself.

Comment: @Munish: In cases like yours where you deal with custom iterators you have to implement this behavior by yourself.

Comment: Can you point to an example code of this versioning mechanism ? There must be standard naming and way to access , because foreach loop will need this check with each MoveNext

Comment: @Munish: No, foreach doesn't do it - it's *within* the MoveNext method. Note that it's pretty rare for you to need to write your own collection classes to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The way this is handled in the collections in the framework, for example the `List<T>` class, is to keep a version number for the state of the list. Whenever the contents of the list is changed in any way, the version number is increased.

The enumerator contains a copy of the version number, so that it can check that the list is unchanged whenever it needs to access the list.

Copying the items when you create the enumerator would circumvent the need for a version counter, but that also makes creating an enumerator expensive. For most collections it's not expensive to create an enumerator, so you should try to follow that behaviour if possible.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on the implementation. Most implementations will not love you if you change the collection during enumeration - and will throw an exception deliberately. However, it is possible (mainly for append-only collections, but possible for all) to write an enumerator that is safe (for example, by enumerating as far as existed when it was created - but multiple designs are possible).

Personally, I would avoid the scenario; it is better to design it so that you are either enumerating *or* mutating, but never both.

If you can't use a collection that *supports* concurrent enumerate and mutate, then taking a copy is feasible, but again - not my preferred option.

Comment: I too like the Snapshot idea. but it is difficult to keep snapshot for a tree like collection because the child node pointers may have changed. But if i just keep in the snapshot enumerator the nodes (without validating their child/parent pointer semantics), then it would work.  Is there any example of concurrent collection in .NET 4 which best handles mutation and enumeration simultaneously with least side-effects ?

Comment: @Munish - the concurrent ones that Jon lists should help. For my own needs, I just wrote my own (I had some very specific requirements, it wasn't *entirely* crazy...)